# How to redirect to a different URL after a video has finished playing

Tags: javascript, html, redirect, video

Hi I'm trying to redirect my page to another address once my video has finished playing and I'm struggling so far. I have adapted the code below from another post on Stack but haven't got it to work.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
<script src="text/javascript">

function playVideo() {
    var video= document.getElementById('video');
    video.play();
    video.addEventListener('ended',function() {
        window.location= 'http://www.google.com';
    });
}

</script>

<video width="1280" height="720" autoplay id="video">
<source src="Jantex_Vid_converted.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

Answer (score 2):

if you write a function, you have to run it

```
<script src="text/javascript">

    function playVideo() {
        var video= document.getElementById('video');
        video.play();
        video.addEventListener('ended',function() {
            window.location= 'http://www.google.com';
        });
    }
    playVideo();
    </script>

    <video width="1280" height="720" autoplay id="video">
    <source src="Jantex_Vid_converted.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    </video>
```

Comment: The autoplay is on, OP should either remove the autoplay, or not execute `video.play` inside the function.

Comment: true, but he was asking why his function wasn't working

Comment: True @Evan, only wanted the OP to read that when he accepts your answer ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't work for two reasons:

**First**: You need to move your javascript code below your HTML code, because you can't refer elements which haven't been created yet.

**Second**: You are begining your javascript code like

```
<script src="text/javascript">
```

and it should be something like

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
```

if you change these two things, i am sure it will work. It does to me.